# Adding web reference but changing accessor to internal

Tags: asp.net, web-services, visual-studio-2010

I am creating a wrapper API around an existing web API. I have added a Web Reference which created the required classes but the default accessor is set to Public. My goal for the project is to completely encapsulate the web API and not have it exposed at all outside of the wrapper API assembly.

Is it possible to change the accessor of the proxy classes in VS 2010 or is there another tool that I should be using?

Thanks.